# Offsite network/data center for disaster recovery

Tags: networking, disaster-recovery, windows

I'm designing an off-site server room for disaster recovery purposes. This off-site space will house duplicates of production servers and backup systems (around 10 Windows systems in total). The backup site and main site LANs will be connected via a WAN link.

My question is: Am I going to be able to keep the IP addresses and server names the same on both networks. Ideally, I'd like the backup site to mirror the main site as much as possible so if there is a problem with the first site, we can fall back to the backup site.

Comment: There is absolutely no way we can know what you will be able to do.

Answer (score 2):

I would stay away from trying to duplicate things like server names or IP addresses in your DR site.  The collision problems this creates (or could create) far out-way the benefits.

Not sure if this helps, but when we implement master/slave topologies, we implement it as it could be master/master topology.  Not that it ever will be (or technically could be due to managing data), but when you use this as a high-level goal, your design from app to administration becomes much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your service providers. Often this can be arranged if both sites are connected to the same ISP (you use BGP and a private AS). Sometimes this can be arranged if the two ISPs are willing to cooperate (same method, but you may have a single point of failure if the two ISPs lose the able to reach each other). It can certainly be arranged if you're a large enough site to have a routable block of addresses and can arrange BGP with both ISPs (public AS).

There should be somebody with a lot of network knowledge at least consulting on this.